# How to recognize Low/High/Band pass filters after FFT?

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm having two zero padded signals in Matlab

```
h_1[n] = {...,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,...} 
h_2[n] = {...,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,...}
```

and below you can see their **FFT** plots:

```
% N1 and N2 are just the lengths of h1 and h2.
H1 = fft(h1, N1); 
H2 = fft(h2, N2);

% ...

figure;
from = -floor(length(H1)/2);
to   = floor(length(H1)/2);
stem(from:to, abs(H1));
```

[image]

[image]

My question is how one can decide whether those are low-,high- or band-pass filters.

I know **FFT** decomposes my functions of time, here `h_1[n]` and `h_2[n]`, into the frequencies of which they are made up: `H_1[k]` and `H_2[k]` if I got that right but so far those plots tell me almost nothing.

So how does one interpret those plots? I don't know why we had to add more zeros to `h_2[n]`, could this be to have a higher sampling rate?

Thank you for any explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are using to generate those plots.

Generally - if you convert the FFT to a polar format it's much easier to interpret.  You end up with one graph for the phase response and one for the frequency response.

I'd recommend a read of this: http://www.dspguide.com/ch8/8.htm

However I think the first one will be a high pass filter (low value at low frequencies, higher value at high frequencies).

If I'm reading your graph right then the second one looks like a band reject?

[image: Polar vs Rectangular Plots]
http://www.dspguide.com/ch8/8.htm

Comment: Hi! I am using Matlab for this (edited this in my question). I have no idea how to transform those into polar. Any idea how I could do that? So the first plot is a high-pass filter because it has low value at low frequencies and higher value at higher freq.? I guess I have to "measure" from the "mirroring-point" right? Sorry for so many questions. This is from a lecture of which I didn't bring all previous required knowledge :D

Comment: The abs function in the OP question does the "polar" conversion.  The stem plots are already magnitude plots.

Comment: Stefan - I think measuring from the mirror point looks right. Band pass should look a bit like this: http://www.ndt.net/article/v07n09/08/fig2.gif

Answer (score 0):

(1) the padded 0s in the two signals are equivalent to interpolation in the frequency domain, thus you can see the denser spectra in the figures.

(2) about h_1[n] and h_2[n], h_2[n] can be treated as an upsampling version of h_1[n] with factor 2, then you can see two replica of the original spectra in the frequency domain.

please refer to "multi-rate signal processing" in digital signal processing textbooks.